# How can I inject custom line breaks on a symbol layer label?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to override the default "text-max-width" label wrapping and inject my own custom line breaks on a symbol feature label? Unfortunately for my current uses, "text-max-width" is strictly defined by em units and not actual character limits.

I'm attempting to break at specific characters and was hoping that setting "text-max-width" to 0 would give me control over line breaks. Currently if I inject "\n" within my string while "text-max-width" = 0, those custom breaks will be ignored and the label will instead be drawn as a single line.

Is there currently a way to work around this in mapbox-gl-js; or would this type of functionality be a new feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification: `\n` in `text-field` is supported since [v0.24.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/releases/tag/v0.24.0). `text-max-width` [defaults to 10em](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-max-width). Setting it to 0 disables all wrapping, including `\n`, in v0.33.1.

This may feel wrong, but setting `text-max-width` to `Infinity` should work.

The code responsible for text wrapping is in [src/symbol/shaping.js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/b1c52e25fe768a851892dc1105b9c679f1a981fb/src/symbol/shaping.js#L53), starting with`shapeText(..., maxSize, ...)`. A quick look didn't reveal any problems with using `Infinity`, but I also found no other way.

Comment: Excellent! That `Infinity`,  did the trick. My label algorithm is now acting as expected. I'll investigate into the src/symbol/shaping.js if I need to manually change anything else regarding this.

Comment: Small note that `all text with symbol-placement: line gets assigned text-max-width: 0 and does not wrap` -- see [issue here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4128).